# In React, replacing URL with an identical value causes infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url

```
      if (new_path !== window.location.pathname + window.location.search) {
        history.replace({
          pathname: new_path,
          search: "",
        });
      }
```

EDITED:

`new_path` is just a string.
Without the if statement, the above code will cause infinite loop.

Is that expected behavior?

Comment: Please provide more as it is unclear which causes loop. May be you have put this logic useEffect with history as dependency array.

Answer (score 0):

It will only cause an infinite loop if

**new_path** is different than **window.location.pathname + window.location.search**.

If you want to check its values, try to preserve logs on chrome developer tools and then start your app. That way you can see why it is generating an infinite loop.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If `new_path` is a state in your app it should be inside `{}`

```
pathname: {new_path}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "if" condition is the wrong one.

```
if (new_path !== window.location.pathname + window.location.search) {}
```

This will be true always and `history.replace` will run again.

so the solution is

```
if (new_path[<your key>] !== window.location[<your key>]) {}
```

If you meant to be the `new_path` is a string, you need to check what is the `new_path` value